# GridView with TextView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, gridview, textview

I am trying to develop small application for Android which computes users concentration. My idea is to show a matrix of images where user is forced to select given images in amount of time and compute how accurate user was.

The problem is that I do not know, how to design a layout which combines TextViews and GridViews.

I tried to make UI like this  but I was not succesfull.

I thought that it is enough to place TextView1 into LinearLayout, then GridView1, TextView2, GridView2 and button. I tried more combinations which led to my failure.

Could you give me a hint how to desing this layout, please?

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView03" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView02" 
        android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="0.4">

    <GridView android:id="@+id/GridView01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="25px"
        android:stretchMode="none">
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" 
                  android:id="@+id/Button01" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
          <Button android:text="@+id/Button02" 
                  android:id="@+id/Button02" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've managed to have more columns in gridview and get there to a single row as many images as I can. But I can't set the height of a row, only width of a column. Images in gridview are magnified and I can't see a method to set them to their original size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  would suggest to nest all thing to a Linear Layout then put 3 Linear Layout

the first will have the upper bar (button s textview etc)
the second will have the Gridview
The third will have the lower bar (button s textview etc)
You can also put in the Linear Layouts fill parent on both height and width and put Layout weight to first 1 to second 0.5 and third 1 and it will put them in the percentage of height you show us in the picture...
Try it and tell us

Comment: Everything works except the gridview, which looks like weird. I updated first post where is my layout with screen of my android device.

Comment: You should not put fill parent to the gridview and horizontal I think

Comment: I've managed to set the gridview to get there more images on a row but these images does not have theirs original size. :-(

Comment: off course because you put image with how many pixels height and width ....You should have the rectangle of the grid the same size...if the images in the gridview are wrap content on both (height and width ) the you can see them with their actual size

Comment: I've solved it. Class ImageAdapter (from droid example) had already set the resolution of imageview - imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(22, 22)). Thanks for your help. There's the screen http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4327086/layout_android.png

Answer (score 0):

I recommend spending a bit of time reading about [Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html). Another good resource is [Hello, Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html), a collection of many good tutorials for how to use different layouts.